# IOS - how do I reset a number label to zero when a button is pressed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, numbers, label

How would I reset a label back to zero that counts up every time the user taps an image?
The current method that I have for it does not work.

Here is the code that I believe you will need:

```
int number = 0;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 
if ([self Intersecting:location :Ball]) {
    number++;

    [labelCurrentNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];

    }
}

-(IBAction)startMove {
    buttonStart.hidden = YES;
    Ball.hidden = NO;
    labelEasy.hidden = YES;
    buttonBack.hidden = YES;

    Destination = CGPointMake(arc4random() % 320, arc4random() % 480); 
    xamt = ((Destination.x - Ball.center.x) / speed);
    yamt = ((Destination.y - Ball.center.y) / speed);

    mainTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.02) target:self selector:@selector(moveBall) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
    mainInt = 20.00;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Please help me out, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just set an integer for the amount you want to change to zero and make the label display that integer. Then all you have to do is code "When the button is pressed, set *integer name here* to 0.

Comment: sorry, im a nub.  Can you explain that in more detail to me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for touch events and calculating intersection, you might want to consider a [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Just add your set to zero method as an target and add the gesture recognizer to your image.